# How to run a node async function locally?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm attempting to write a Node async function and run test it locally. I have this function (using nano for CouchDB):

```
async function calldb() {

    console.log("entering calldb")

    const q = {
       ... query def ...
    };

    try {
        console.log("before await")
        const response = await nano.db.find(q)
        console.log("after await")
    } catch (e) {
        return { Error: e}
    }

    console.log(response);
    return response;

}
```

I want to test locally, so I'm doing `npx run-func getGoods.js calldb`. This yields:

```
npx run-func index.js calldb
npx: installed 1 in 0.91s
entering calldb
before await
```

The first console log runs, but then it doesn't wait around for the response from the db.

How can I test this locally to see if I am actually connecting to the Couch database? How can I get the return from the db call to log to console?

Comment: Since your not getting `after await`, you should put a `console.log(e)` inside your `catch` block because you are perhaps getting an error, but not logging it.

Comment: It stopped at `return { Error: e}`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code of the library that you indicate (https://github.com/DVLP/run-func/blob/master/index.js), it does not wait for an async function.

If you want to use that library you would need to change the code.